# How to prove the modulus of $\frac{z-w}{z-\bar{w}} < 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $\Im{(z)} > 0$ and $\Im{(w)} > 0$, prove that $|\displaystyle\frac{z-w}{z-\bar{w}}|<1$ .

Please help me check my answer:

$z - w = a + ib$

$z - \bar{w}$ = $a + i(b+2\Im(w)) $

$|\displaystyle\frac{z-w}{z-\bar{w}}$| =  $\displaystyle\frac{|a+ib|}{|a+i(b+2\Im(w)|}$

= $\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)}}{\sqrt(a^2+(b+2\Im(w))^2)}$

< $\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)}}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)}}$ = 1

Comment: @Dror: Since it was assumed that $\Im z>0$ and $\Im w>0,$ we *do* have strict inequality, and *cannot* have $z=\overline w.$

Comment: @ Dror: i have edited my ans. Is it correct?

Comment: Seems to be correct, but it doesn't prove what you want, yet.

Comment: Now It's full, but also not too "pretty", and assumes square root is increasing ;)

Comment: thank you :) How to improve my ans?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If $z-w=a+ib$, then $z- \overline{w}=a+i(b+2\Im(w))$.

Comment: +1: Very nice hint! I deleted my own out of sheer embarrassment. :-/

Comment: @CameronBuie I see I'm not the only one with over-self-criticism issues... :)

Comment: @CameronBuie I just corrected the my **mistake**, and added a $2$ factor!

Comment: Good catch! :-)

Answer (score 0):

An example of *almost* pretty proof (In my eyes of course) using all the givens implicitly:
$$x \equiv z-w \implies y \equiv z - \overline{w}=x+2i\Im{(w)} \implies 0 <|x|^2 < |y|^2 \implies  |\frac{x}{y}|^2=\frac{|x|^2}{|y|^2}<1 \implies |\frac{z-w}{z - \overline{w}}|=|\frac{x}{y}|<1$$